# Lifetime of temporary objects in SWIG's Python wrappers (?)

Tags: c++, python, swig, lifetime, temporary-objects

**Edited 12 Feb**

I've just recently come up with an odd crash using some SWIG-generated Python wrappers for some C++ classes.  It seems that the combination of SWIG and Python together are somewhat eager to clean up temporary values.  So eager, in fact, that they're cleaned up while they're still being used.  A significantly condensed version looks like this:

```
/* Example.hpp */
struct Foo {
    int value;
    ~Foo();
};

struct Bar {
    Foo theFoo;
    Bar();
};

/* Example.cpp */
#include "Example.hpp"
Bar::Bar()  {theFoo.value=1;}
Foo::~Foo() {value=0;}

/* Example.i */
%module Example
%{
#include "Example.hpp"
%}
%include "Example.hpp"
```

I run SWIG (1.3.37) on the .i file, and then in Python, have:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sept 17 2008, 16:07:08)
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-41)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.
>>> from Example import Bar
>>> b=Bar()
>>> print b.theFoo.value      # expect '1', since Bar's constructor sets this
1
>>> print Bar().theFoo.value  # expect '1', since we're still using the Foo object
26403424
```

It seems that in the second instance, the temporary `Bar` object is destroyed before we ever get to read `theFoo`'s `value` field.  Chasing things around in gdb, this is clearly what's happening.  And so by the time we read `.value` from `Bar().theFoo`, C++ has already destroyed (and overwritten with some other heap allocation) `.theFoo`.  In my actual situation, this is causing a segfault.

Is there any SWIG directive or trick that I can add to my `Example.i` file to make `Bar().theFoo.value` return `1` here?

Comment: let me know if my answer solved your problem, or what solution you found -- this was an interesting question!

Comment: Sadly, the conclusion has been "live with it".  No good solution presented itself =(

Answer (score 2):

**Second Update**:

Well we know that the basic problem is that python destroys `Bar` immediately. When `Bar` is implemented in python, python's gc knows that there's still a reference to `theFoo`, and so does not destroy it. But when `Bar` is implemented in c++, python calls the c++ destructor, which automatically destroys `theFoo` along with `Bar.`

So the obvious solution is to prevent python from destroying `Bar` prematurely. Here's a slightly hackish solution involving subclassing `Bar`:

```
class PersistentBar(swigexample.Bar):
    lastpbar = None
    def __init__(self):
        super(PersistentBar, self).__init__()
        PersistentBar.lastpbar = self
```

This saves a reference to the last `Bar` created so that it isn't destroyed right away. When a new `Bar` is created, the old one is deleted. (My old version was silly; no need to override `__del__` for this.) Here's the output (with `cout << "deleting Foo "` in `Foo`'s destructor):

```
>>> from test import persistentBar
>>> persistentBar().theFoo.value
1
>>> persistentBar().theFoo.value
deleting Foo 1
>>> persistentBar().theFoo.value
deleting Foo 1
```

I still don't love this. It might be better to sequester the "persistent" behavior in a decorator; I tried that too and it worked (if you want to see the code let me know). It would definitely be better to somehow tell python to handle destroying `theFoo` itself, but I can't figure out how to do that.

**First Update**:

The wrap code told me nothing, so I looked in swigexample.py. That also yielded nothing. Things became clearer when I tried duplicating `Bar` in pure python:

```
# pyfoobar.py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = -1

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.theFoo = Foo()
        self.theFoo.value = 1
    def __del__(self):
        self.theFoo.value = 0
```

Now we import Bar from pyfoobar:

```
>>> from pyfoobar import Bar
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.theFoo.value
1
>>> Bar().theFoo.value
0
```

This behavior is coming from Python!

**Original Answer**:

It seems like there's definitely some garbage collection combat at work here... Here's some related information on [SWIG Memory Management](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn30). Based on this, it looks like the %newobject directive might be what you're looking for; but I tried several variations and couldn't get it to give python control over `theFoo`:

```
>>> from swigexample import Bar
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.theFoo.value
1
>>> b.theFoo.thisown
False
>>> Bar().theFoo.value
0
>>> Bar().theFoo.thisown
False
```

I'm beginning to suspect that this is intentional; seems like this line from the above link is relevant here:

> C is now holding a reference to the
>   object---you probably don't want
>   Python to destroy it.

But I'm not certain. I'm going to look at the swigexample_wrap code to see if I can figure out when `~Bar` is being called.

Comment: Certainly a good answer to the situation I posed.  Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my real problem.  I think I need to rework my original question some.

Comment: Ok, changed the question to better fit the real problem.

Comment: I also tried writing my changed example up in pure python, following your example.  In pure Python (i.e. with a __del__ method in Foo), Bar().theFoo.value == 1, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add %naturalvar to your .i file like this:

```
%naturalvar Bar::theFoo;
%include "Example.hpp"
```

This causes SWIG to return a copy of Foo instead of a reference to it, which solves the problem of aggressive temporary object cleanup that Python does.